# How to avoid double escape (\\) when reading a string from a csv file in Python?

Tags: python

This is a test code that is working just fine:

```
x = "b'\x12'"
y = x[2:-1]
z = y.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
print (z, int.from_bytes(z, 'big'))
```

which gives the expected result:

```
b'\x12' 18
```

Now I want to do the same, except for storing the initial string in a csv file:

1. I create a `test.csv` file with this content:

   ```
    name,value
    item,"b'\x12'"
   ```
2. I create an adapted test code:

   ```
    import csv

    with open("test.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for row in reader:
            if row["name"] == "item":
                x = row["value"]

    print ("x:", x, type(x))
    y = x[2:-1]
    z = y.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
    print ("z:", z, int.from_bytes(z, 'big'))
   ```

which gives:

```
x: b'\x12' <class 'str'>
z: b'\\x12' 1551380786
```

What should I do to avoid the double \ and get the same result as in the first test code?

(purpose is to obtain the real byte from the literal str representation of that byte, when the literal str representation is stored in a csv file)

Comment: if you print x ... its likely not what you think it is

Comment: I do print x before and it is what I think it should be – a string. I edited the code above to reflect this.

Comment: They're _all_ printed as double escapes in any context that prints Python representation. When you store `\x12` in a file _as four characters_, the first of those characters is one that Python represents _as two slashes_, even though it's really only one. The only way to get a Python representation to have only one slash is to have your string _not contain a literal slash at all_.

Comment: For example, think of the Python string `'\t'`. There's only one character in that string -- and it's a tab, not a slash. That string contains no slashes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ascii codec has no understanding of \x## encoding so it becomes a literal \ follwed by x followed by 2 numbers... a literal \ is represented as 2 backslashes in python.

one way to deal with it is to convert it back to bytes using raw_unicode_escape, and then use normal unicode_escape to convert it back to a string

```
>>> s = "\\x12"
>>> type(s),repr(s)
(<class 'str'>, "'\\\\x12'")
>>> s_bytes=s.encode("raw_unicode_escape")|
>>> type(s_bytes),repr(s_bytes)
(<class 'bytes'>, "b'\\\\x12'")
>>> s2 = s_bytes.decode("unicode_escape")
type(s2),repr(s2)
(<class 'str'>, "'\\x12'")
>>> s2
'\x12'
>>> print(s2)
```

you could also do something like this with regex substitution

```
import re
s = "\\x12"
s2 = re.sub(r"\\x(\d{2})",lambda m:chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
```

there are many ways to solve this, but here are 2 ways

**but generally speaking using csv to store binary data is a bad idea.. and making up your own encoding is also probably not the best practice**

you should use something like base64 to turn binary data into ascii, or you should use an actual encoding when writing the file that will represent \x12 however you are expecting that to be represented

if it is **really** guaranteed to be a literal of a simple python object you can use

```
import ast
a_byte_str = ast.literal_eval("b'\\x12'")
print(a_byte_str,a_byte_str[0])
```

Comment: While I agree with "using csv to store binary data is a bad idea", in my above test code I assumed a *literal* representation of a binary data (byte, in this case), not the actual binary data. Probably I should have write `item,"b'\x12'"` on the second line of my test.csv file to be more clear on this (but that does not change the result). However, my purpose is to obtain in the end the **real byte** from the literal str representation of that byte, not to obtain another str.

Comment: see my edit to answer that question

Comment: Yes, the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) solved my question and yes, in my actual user case the byte representation is guaranteed to be always literal (but I can also add a prior checking to make sure the literal condition is always met).